# __doPostBack does not fire server side MenuItemClick event for overrided menu item from javascript

Tags: asp.net, menu, webforms, server-side, server-side-scripting

I have asp.net Menu with server side click event. Menu renders properly with __doPostBack event for each menu item. 
But when I am overriding one of the menu item from javascript to pass different argument, it does fire server event but not Protected Sub menuBar_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles menuBar.MenuItemClick event.

Menu item renders like

```
    <a class="menuBar_1 staticMenuItem menuBar_3" 
style="font-size: 1em;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucPageHeader1$menuBar','6')"> 
Link 1</a>


    <a class="menuBar_1 staticMenuItem menuBar_4" 
style="font-size: 1em;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ucPageHeader1$menuBar','7')"> 
Link 2</a>
```

Overriding in javascript as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".menuBar_1 staticMenuItem menuBar_4").on( "click", function() {
handleChange();
    });
});

function function handleChange(){
 __doPostBack("ctl00$ucPageHeader1$menuBar", "74");
}
```

Somehow clicking on Link 1 is able to fire menuBar_MenuItemClick but not for Link 2.

For both link click I do get ?request("__EVENTTARGET") = "ctl00$ucPageHeader1$menuBar" in immediate window.

Any guesses ?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.
An argument that I was passing "74" was not available in any of menu item's value.
So I had to add new menu item with value of 74 and hide it from javascript.

I hope this might help someone.